# Custom steps for a Windows Phone Slider

Tags: windows-phone-7

I would like to use a slider that only allows round numbers. So for example, a slide from 0 to 10, that would only allow 0, 1, 2... values. Is it possible with the native control ?

Comment: Sliders are often difficult to use on a touchscreen device -- make sure you test on device to ensure it meets your usability requirements.

Comment: +1 Testing on a real device is important as the emulator has the advantage of using a mouse (high accuracy). Also, avoid putting a Slider on any control that also requires horizontal movement (e.g. a Pivot). It's not a great user experience, even if Sliders can be tapped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Slider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.slider%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) control. Set the [Minimum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.rangebase.minimum%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) and [Maximum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.rangebase.maximum%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) properties to 0 and 10, respectively. Then, set the [SmallChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.rangebase.smallchange%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) and [LargeChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.rangebase.largechange%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) properties to whole values so that they can only increment in whole numbers. Presumably SmallChange will be `1.0` in this case.